# Setting default time causes binding issues in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, time, bind, default

I've a time input box in my app

```
<input type="time" name="time" ng-model="time" 
min="09:00:00" max="22:00:00" ng-change="yesorno()" required />
... some other HTML data
{{time | date: "h:mm a"}}
```

In my controller I have

```
$scope.yesorno = function() {
    $scope.time // get data and set true or false to other values
};
```

This whole thing works fine and the data changes as I change the time in the textbox.

However, I need to set a default value for the input box, and through searching, I discovered this method.

```
$scope.time = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '<?php echo isset($_GET['time']) ? $_GET['time'] : '10:00'; ?>');
```

It is successful in letting me have a default value in the input box, but all of the sudden, `{{time | date: "h:mm a"}}` goes blank when I change the time input box, and `$scope.time` is undefined in the console log.

I need some advise on how to set default time while still retaining the data binding.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a function on the controller to give you back the time? If there isn't one 'set' in your input, give it back a default time:

```
function retrieveTime() {
  return $scope.time || new Date(//Your Time/Date);
}
```

Then your template becomes:

```
{{ retrieveTime() | date: "h:mm a" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution.

```
<input type="time" name="time" id="timei" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['time']) ? $_GET['time'] : '10:00'; ?>"
        min="09:00:00" max="22:00:00" onchange="bindTime()" required />
```

I do not bind my time input box with angularjs. Instead, I treat it like a normal HTML5 time box where I can set default time with the value attribute. Then I use the onchange attribute to call a function outside of my controller to interact with the scope

```
function bindTime () {
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('appwrap')).scope();
    scope.time = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + document.getElementById('timei').value);
    scope.$apply();
}
```

This works well on mobile browser too.